# ScrollHeight not updated after route navigation

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a component who need to check if document vertical scrollbar is present or no to know if more data need to be loaded.

I created a function to check the scrollbar state and i execute it in NgAfterViewInit, if the page is loaded directly all is ok but if i navigate and return to the page the scrollHeight value is that of the previous page.

I Added a SetTimeout to check a little bit after view init and it's working, but I'd like to know if there isn't a cleaner solution.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.checkScrollBarState();
    }, 50)
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.resizeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  checkScrollBarState() {
    const scrollBarState = this.getScrollBarState()
    console.log(scrollBarState.vScrollbar);
    if(!scrollBarState.vScrollbar) {
      this.loadMoreResults(true);
    }
  }

  loadMoreResults(checkScrollBarStateAfter?: boolean) {
    console.log('scroll');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cards.push(...this.LIST);
      if(checkScrollBarStateAfter) {
        this.checkScrollBarState();
      }
    }, 500);
  }

   getScrollBarState() {
    var result = {vScrollbar: true, hScrollbar: true};
    try {
      var root = document.documentElement;
      console.log(root.scrollHeight);
      console.log(root.clientHeight)
      result.vScrollbar = root.scrollHeight > root.clientHeight;
      result.hScrollbar = root.scrollWidth > root.clientWidth;
    } catch(e) {}
    return(result);
  }
```